# Is there a SQL Server function that transform a varchar to an int?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to transform a `varchar` to an `int` or `bigint`, I used the `CheckSum()` function but in some cases, it returns the same value of two different `varchar`.

Is there a similar function that returns an unique int?

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should add  a proper data sample you actual result and your expetced  result .. youn should also look at cast and convert

Comment: Maybe try try_cast( somecolumn as int)

Comment: If the varchar is a number it converts implicitly.  select '1'+1 returns 2

Comment: the varchar is not always a number, it could be like this 731221731221BPCA

Comment: what integer should '731221731221BPCA' convert to?

Comment: I'm actually not interrested of the value of the Int that I should get. What I'm looking for is to get for each varchar a unique int.

Comment: `CHECKSUM` doesn't provide a unique value for every value, it only returns `int`, so it's impossible for it to, nor is it designed to. It's *design* to basically do what it says on the tin; to be used as a checking value. For example, large downloads often come with a checksum value; these downloads can be several GBs in size, which in bytes is a far larger number than an `int` could ever hope to hold. The Checksum value, however, is used to validate against the checksum provided with the download, to confirm the file is identical to the source.

Comment: What *other* characters could you string contain? If it just alphanumerics?  Are letters always uppoercase? Could it contain whitespace (`' '`), hyphens (`-`), periods (`.`), commas (`,`), accented letters (`é`), or any other character? Are they a fixed width or variable?

Comment: @Larnu, What is your thought on `BINARY_CHECKSUM`?

Comment: Is the varchar column the primary key and you want to replace the pk with an int?

Comment: SteveC yes ! the varchar column is the the primary key, and I'm looking to transforming it to an int

Comment: You can make that column to `UNIQUE` and create a another column with `INT` and make it as `IDENTITY`, that should be simple

Comment: Lamu, it can be anything but they are limited to 20 caracters.

Comment: @Sowmyadhar Gourishetty, the problem is the user can change these varchar values,

he can swipe Varchar1 and Varchar2, and if I add the ID column it will not be correct because ID = 1 will be varchar2 and ID=2 will be Varchar1

Comment: what is the issue that you will see when the varchar is modified? you can update the modified varchar to the same column, it will still have the unique primary key attached to it.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4,294,967,296 different values of integers.

There are way, way more combinations of strings.  For just 10 characters using numbers and letters, there are 3,656,158,440,062,976 possibilities.

3 quadrillion things cannot be put into 4 billion buckets.  This actually has a name, the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).  You are going to get collisions.

What you *can* do is put your strings into a table with an `int` or `bigint` as the key.  Then use this `key` to identify the string.

Answer (score 1):

This script drops the varchar primary key and replaces it with a unique constraint.  Then it adds a new BIGINT Identity primary key.

```
drop table if exists SomeTable;
go
create table SomeTable(pk_char_id            varchar(16) constraint pk_varchar_id primary key not null);
insert SomeTable values ('abc123'), ('xyz456');

/* drop the existing primary key constraint (by name) */
alter table SomeTable
drop constraint pk_varchar_id;

/* add new unique constraint on the old primary key column */
alter table SomeTable
add constraint unq_SomeTable_pci unique (pk_char_id);   

/* drop the existing primary key constraint (by name) */
alter table SomeTable
add
  pk_id                 bigint identity(1, 1) primary key not null;
```

Results

```
pk_char_id  pk_id
abc123      1
xyz456      2
```

Comment: I agree with the solution, this is simple and best unless you have some other complications.

Comment: Are there any dependencies on the vachar primary key?  Is it a foreign key in any other table(s)?

Comment: it's the primary key and there is other tables that has it as a foreign key...

Comment: Well that does complicates this because the keys in the other tables should be dealt with as well

Comment: Please let me know if there's something more I could do here.  I'm not sure how to update the answer without knowing more about the DDL and indexes etc.

Comment: I think that the best solution is to tranform the varchar to a concatenation of ascii code.